# How to copy content of generic object for specific object

Tags: object, request, polymorphism, clone

I need a support in this code, I have a method that I get generic object and a String, so according to the String I get I want to copy the contents of the generic object to
specific object, one observation that Object TypeA don't have same fields that TypeB. for example:

Thanks in advance

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Authorize("Receiving")
@Path("/Print")

public Response LabelPrint(@Context HttpServletRequest request, 
                            final Object generic
                           ,@QueryParam("Type") final String Type) {

    if ( Typex.compareTo("X")) {

        TypeA typeA = generic;
        ...

    } else {
        TypeB typeB = generic;
        ...
    }

    return buildResponse(OK);
```

}

I tried that away, but unsuccessfully

```
    if (labelType.compareTo("X")) {             
        TypeA x = new TypeA();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(x, generic);
    }
    else {
        TypeA y = new TypeA();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(y, generic);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it that away, receiving how String

```
public Response LabelPrint(@Context HttpServletRequest request, 
                            final String objetcForImpression
                           ,@QueryParam("Type") final String Type) {

    if ( Typex.compareTo("X")) {

            try {
                ObjectMapper objetcForImpression  = new ObjectMapper(); 
                TypeA typeA = objetcForImpression.readValue(objetcForImpression, TypeA.class);                  
            } catch (JsonParseException e) {                
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
    }

        ...

    } else {
            try {
                ObjectMapper objetcForImpression  = new ObjectMapper(); 
                TypeB typeB = objetcForImpression.readValue(objetcForImpression, TypeA.class);                  
            } catch (JsonParseException e) {                
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
    }

    return buildResponse(OK);
```

}